# Split Lines function bug - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having the most bizarre problem on my project : I use a custom function to split the lines in spans while the components are mounted, here is the said function

```js
function splitLines(container, opentag, closingtag, className) {
  let spans = container.children,
    top = 0,
    tmp = "";
  container.innerHTML = container.textContent.replace(
    /\S+/g,
    `<span class='${className} inlineBlock'>$&</span>`
  );

  for (let i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    let rect = spans[i].getBoundingClientRect().y;

    if (top < rect) {
      tmp += closingtag + opentag;
      top = rect;
    }
    tmp += spans[i].outerHTML + " ";
  }
  container.innerHTML = tmp + closingtag;
}

export default splitLines
```

it's not totally working , indeed, the lines are not correctly splitted :
[image]

but when I change the page and then come back, the problem is solved (but if I refresh, we're back to square one) [image]

Am I not triggering the function as soon as the component is mounted ? Is the function flawed ?
If you have any idea how I could resolve my issue please share them :)

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
    splitLines(
      presentationTextRef.current,
      "<span class= 'hidden inlineBlock'>",
      "</span>",
      "presWords"
    );

    const presTL = gsap.timeline({
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: "#Presentation",
        start: "top center",
        end: "bottom center",
        id: "Presentation",
        toggleActions: "play reverse restart reverse",
      },
    });

    const presWords = gsap.utils.toArray("#Presentation .presWords");

    presTL.from(presWords, {
      yPercent: 200,
      stagger: 0.05,
    });
    return () => {
      presTL.kill();
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: You shouldn't manipulate the DOM like that in react. What are you trying to achieve? There is probably a better way which doesn't evolve using innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that is more fitted I think to the reactjs way of things (meaning : that doesn't manipulate the DOM directly).
Here it is

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
// gsap
import gsap, { Power3 } from "gsap";

export default function AnimatedWords(props) {
  const { text, delay } = props;
  const words = text.split(" ");
  const wordsRef = useRef([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    gsap.to(wordsRef.current, {
      y: 0,
      stagger: 0.05,
      delay: delay ? delay : 0,
      ease: Power3.easeOut,
    });
  });
  return (
    <span>
      {words.map((word, idx) => (
        <span style={{ display: "inline-block", overflow: "hidden" }}>
          <span
            key={idx}
            ref={(el) => (wordsRef.current[idx] = el)}
            className="animatedLetter"
            style={{
              display: "inline-block",
              transform: "translate(0, 200px)",
            }}
          >
            {/* '&nbsp' is used to create spaces between              the words, it produces a non-breaking space*/}
            {word}&nbsp;
          </span>
        </span>
      ))}
    </span>
  );
}
```

What do you think ? use refs in a map function is always such a hassle, I wonder if I should have used createRef ?

Thanks anyway !